# Java execute "time curl -s" command

Tags: java, curl

I am wanting to execute this command:

```
time curl -s 'URL HERE'
```

In Java and get the results such as:

```
real    0m0.293s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.052s
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Write some code? We're not here to do that for you. You write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: I went to answer this question and found out that it's actually surprisingly difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way you execute a command would be to call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` will execute the command you give it. However, there's several caveats:

First, `time` is a shell built-in command. If you just call

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("time curl -s 'http://www.google.com/'");
```

then you'll get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "time": error=2, No such file or directory
```

It looks like you can fix this with `sh -c`:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c \"time curl -s 'http://www.google.com/'\"");
```

But you can't. `exec()` splits the string you give it by arguments using a space character without regard to quotes! This is annoying. You can fix that with `ProcessBuilder`:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "time curl -s 'http://www.google.com/'").start();
```

This command won't fail, but it also won't appear to do anything! This is because Java doesn't automatically send the output of commands executed to standard out. If you want to do this, you have to manually copy the output:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "time curl -s 'http://www.google.com/'").start();
InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
int i;
while (-1 != (i = in.read())){
    System.out.write(i);
}
```

This copies the output, but not the error. You can do the same copy procedure with `process.getErrorStream()` (which returns an `InputStream`). You could also use `redirectErrorStream()`:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "time curl -s 'http://www.google.com/'").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
int i;
while (-1 != (i = in.read())){
    System.out.write(i);
}
```

and ***THAT*** is how you properly execute the command in Java.

**EDIT:** [You could also download the file in Java natively.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) In that case, you can use `System.nanoTime()` to calculate how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the API Class: [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)